# iOS Realm object by reference or duplicate objects

Tags: ios, realm

I am using realm and I am not sure about this.

[image]

I have two option to do in Post. One is to save entire owner object and another is to save only user object ID. If I save entire object, is it object by reference? I don't want to increase database size.

The reason why I want to store entire object is that it is easy to access. It is like Post.User.email. I don't need to query. I read through realm though. https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No need to go by ID. In Realm, when you add a property of another `RealmObject` type, that will store the reference, not the entire object. So it will not take more space on disk than what you are expecting.

I am not sure if your diagram reflects your actual types, but note that when using collections, you want them to be of type `RealmList<>`, not `Array<>` (I am assuming you are writing C# as you referred to the Xamarin docs).

Comment: Sorry. I use link wrongly. it should be objc. Thanks for your help. Let me check first.