# Realm Swift - save a reference to another object

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I thought this would be pretty straightforward after reading [here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#relationships) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37716066/ios-realm-object-by-reference-or-duplicate-objects) but I'm a bit stuck.

I have a 'favouriteWorkout' object that looks like this :

```
class FavouriteObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic var favouriteWorkoutName = ""
    @objc dynamic var workoutReference = WorkoutSessionObject()

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "favouriteWorkoutName"
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is reference a `WorkoutSessionObject` in Realm that links from a WorkoutName when a workout is saved as a favourite.

My WorkoutSessionObject has a primary key of `workoutID` which is a `UUID` string. It looks like this :

```
class WorkoutSessionObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic var workoutID = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var workoutType = ""
    let exercises = List<WorkoutExercise>()
    @objc dynamic var totalExerciseCount = 0
    @objc dynamic var rounds = 0
    @objc dynamic var favourite : Bool = false

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "workoutID"
    }
}
```

I've then tried to save using this :

```
let favouriteWorkout = FavouriteObject()
favouriteWorkout.favouriteWorkoutName = favouriteName
favouriteWorkout.workoutReference = (realm.object(ofType: WorkoutSessionObject.self, forPrimaryKey: self.workoutID))!

do {
    try realm.write {
        realm.add(favouriteWorkout)
    }
} catch {
    print ("Error adding favourite")
}
```

but i get a crash when I run of :

> 'RLMException', reason: 'The `FavouriteObject.workoutReference` property must be marked as being optional.

However, when I then try to make it optional (by adding ?) it says

> "Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'WorkoutSessionObject"!

**Summary**

I want to save a reference of the `workoutID` of a `WorkoutSessionObject` in my `FavouriteObject` which is an actual link to the `WorkoutSessionObject` (so the properties can be accessed from favourites)

**Update**

using the answers below I've now sorted the problem of the workout reference.  This is now showing in Realm as the proper format () under "workoutReference".  However, I'm now getting "nil" in "workoutReference" when trying to save.  I know the workoutID is coming through correctly as I am printing it in the console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the declaration of `workoutReference`. First of all, you need to make it `Optional` by writing `?` after the *type*. Secondly, you shouldn't assign a default value to it, it needs to be `Optional` for a reason. The [linked docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#relationships) clearly state that

> to-one relationships must be optional

, and `workoutReference` is clearly a to-one relationship.

```
class FavouriteObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic var favouriteWorkoutName = ""
    @objc dynamic var workoutReference:WorkoutSessionObject?

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "favouriteWorkoutName"
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks this worked now and the reference is now correct in the DB - i'm getting "nil" when trying to save though ... is my save function also wrong?

Comment: @nc14 are you getting `nil` for `FavouriteObject` or `workoutReference`? Where exactly are you getting this `nil`?

Comment: @nc14 please edit your question to include the code where `workoutReference` is `nil`.

Comment: Sorry this might not be what you mean, but my 'save' block is in the question under "I've then tried to save with this:"

Comment: @nc14 I get that, but in your "save block" it is not possible for `workoutReference` to be `nil`, since you are assigning a non-Optional value to it. Are you trying to retrieve `FavouriteObject` from Realm after your write transaction and that's where `workoutReference` is nil? If that's the case, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50874280/realm-swift-save-a-reference-to-another-object/50874423?noredirect=1#comment88750723_50874423) your question to include the updated code and show where the issue is.

Comment: It is working now - i needed to update realm with a migration block and go to the new instance - thanks so much :-)

Answer (score 2):

In [property-cheatsheet](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#property-cheatsheet) you can see that a non-optional `Object`-property is not allowed, so you have to change it like the following:

```
class FavouriteObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic var favouriteWorkoutName = ""
    // here you have to make the property optional
    @objc dynamic var workoutReference: WorkoutSessionObject?

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "favouriteWorkoutName"
    }
}
```